# Custom Sonar Rule To Check For Correct Method Call

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have my custom SonarQube plugIn up and running on a local SonarQube server and it works fine. Now I want to add more stuff to it. I'm interested in coding my own Sonar Rule which checks if the non deprecated constructor is used for one class.

Possible constructor calls:

```
@Deprecated
public ExampleClass(String a) 
{
    //deprecated/old/wrong stuff happening
}
public ExampleClass(String a, String b)
{
    //correct stuff happening
}
```

I'm already at the state, that only `Method` notes will be visited.

Now I'm wondering how can I check which `new ExampleClass` expression is used?

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution. 
Here's what I did:

1. set `nodesToVisit` to `Tree.Kind.ASSIGNMENT`
2. check if the expression is `Tree.Kind.NEW_CLASS`
3. check if `identifier` is `ExampleClass.class.getSimpleName()`
4. do my argument checks

Code:

```
AssignmentExpressionTree assignment = (AssignmentExpressionTree) tree;

    if ( assignment.expression().is(Tree.Kind.NEW_CLASS) )
    {
        NewClassTreeImpl expression = (NewClassTreeImpl) assignment.expression();
        IdentifierTreeImpl identifier = (IdentifierTreeImpl) expression.identifier();

        if ( StringUtils.equals(identifier.name(), ExampleClass.class.getSimpleName()) )
        {
            ArgumentListTreeImpl arguments = (ArgumentListTreeImpl) expression.arguments();

            if ( arguments.size() != 2 )
            {
                reportIssue(expression, "Use the 2 parameter constructor call when creating new ExampleClass objects!");
            }
            else if ( StringUtils.indexOfAny(arguments.get(1).symbolType().name(), POSSIBLE_PARAMETER_TYPES) == -1 )
            {
                reportIssue(expression, "The second parameter must be from type String");
            }
        }
    }
```

If you find any improvement of my rule, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You can set NodesToVisit to NEW_CLASS directly : because here you won't detect cases such as `someCall(new Example...)` only when you assign directly the constructor.